# Finding the volume of a real egg if the volume of an egg shape(with different dimensions) on a graph is known

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

[image]

Equation of the egg shown above:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If the volume of the egg show above is: $12.00405units^3$(found using calculus)

if the volume of a real egg is $55cm^3$

Is there anyway of finding out the volume of a real egg theoretically(i.e. only using the value obtained using calculus or find a scale factor for the volume of the egg in the graph and the volume of a real egg

Answer (score 0):

You have used two parameters (u,v) and a constant $r$.

To me appears, variation of $r = ( 0.. 1) $ is incorrect, you assumed a constant value for $r_1$

You need to multiply by a factor.

$$ r_2 = r_1 \left( \frac{55}{ 12.00405}\right)  ^ {1/3} $$

to get a bigger egg.

Comment: why is the power 1/3?

Comment: Like.. volumes of two spheres are in proportion of their radii cubed.

Comment: Oh yes, Im sorry I understand

Comment: Wait so for me r1 is just 1?. And I will have to find the volume again with r2 that find, using what you gave above?. I needed r1 because the Jacobian matrix needs 3 variables.

Comment: okay if thats okay with you

Comment: okay i'll come here and msg you at 6 30. Thanks for the help

Comment: is it possible for me to do this to get a scale factor:  (4.1/2.5) where 4.1 is the diameter of a real egg in cm and 2.5units is the diameter of the egg in the graph

Comment: I think so, but why Jacobian when you are dealing with a geometrically similar ( one constant parameter scaled up) surface?

Comment: Thats cause the essay that I am writing is about multiple integrals. It is true that I can use volume of solid of revolution for this but I can't cause it does not  involve multiple integrals

Comment: When considering change of variables to find new volume we can express  $ \int \int \int  J \cdot  du dv dw $

Comment: Yes  I already did that

Comment: Yes, please move it to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30968/discussion-between-narasimham-and-anjaney-m).